# Poco::Data::Session how create file database?

Tags: c++, poco

I use the POCO library and I need to create a database SQLite at the beginning of my program so that I can then write and read data into it. How can I do it?
I wrote the following code:

```
std::filesystem::path data_root_path("var/opt");
auto data_dir_path = data_root_path / "agent" / "data" / "module";
auto database_file = data_dir_path / "database.db";
// register SQLite connector
Poco::Data::SQLite::Connector::registerConnector();
database_ = Poco::makeShared<Poco::Data::Session("SQLite",database_file.string());
```

But I get the following error:
`FileNotFound`
I work on Linux OS, maybe I don't have access rights to create a database file? How can I check this? I gave the local user write access to the folder.

Could you tell me how to create a database file using the library POCO?

Comment: Check that current user have access rights for a folder `data_dir_path`.  See https://mason.gmu.edu/~montecin/UNIXpermiss.htm To check you can use `ls -lah /var/opt/nf-agent/data/LDPModule` command. See also https://kb.iu.edu/d/abdb